# Display color calibration error "unknown calibration display type selection"

Tags: display, monitor, 15.04, colors, color-management

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 15.04.
Running Settings-Color-Calibrate
Have "Eye-one display 2" sensor connected and working.
Getting the message during step be step calibration configuration: "calibration error unknown calibration display type selection"

This never happened in 14.04 or 14.10 where calibration went smoothly with this color calibration sensor device.

Comment: Hi. I have got the same problem. Could it be that your calibration device does not support the specified display type? Did you try calibrating with different display types?

Comment: Actually my current issue seems related the updated Ubuntu 15.04 calibration toolchain. Before upgrade the same X-Rite eye-one display 2 worked fine. It actually works fine even now with dispcalGUI applications.

The difference I have noticed since upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 is that "System settings-Color-Calibrate" now offers the wide variety of backlite profiles.

Comment: As my DELL U2410f has the advanced CCFL backlit type it now could be calibrated with this option. But "Next" step failed exactly after choosing any of types.

With dispcalGUI I could calibrate but for me it's too complex.